# Battery Issue Dell Inspiron 15 Plugged in , Not Charging

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I have Dell Laptop Inspiron 15 3000 Series which i bought it couple days ago, by default it has windows 8.1 i figured out there's a delay in charging when i plug in the charger.

I have a problems with windows 8.1 So i format and install windows 10, i notice that when i plug the charger it gives me not charging.

I google the problem, i stopped by some solutions such as:

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19451836

For this solution i update the drivers and i update BIOS, but no result the same Problem appears plugged in, Not charging.

I tired this method in the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L09UVtZuzIY

But also nothing happens.

Then i tried to replace the AC power charger with another one that have the same Output(45W), It gives me the same result Plugged in, Not charging !!!!!

Really i'm tired with this, can anyone help me?

> Update: When i enter BIOS settings in Battery Information Battery, under battery picture these information is given:

- idle
- battery health: Excellent
- AC 45W

Comment: Are you using the power adaptor supplied with the laptop? If so it could be that the shop gave you an incompatible charger. Does it have a light on it anywhere to show that the charger itself is working? We use Dells at my place of work, some laptops require 60W AC to charge, others require 90W to charge. You may need a bigger power supply...

Edit - The specs say this : Inspiron 15-3551 45W, Inspiron 15-3558 45W  65W.

If yours is a 3558 it may require 65W to charge but run with 45W. Alternatively the charge circuit in the laptop could be broken.

Comment: "i bought it couple days ago" Return it under warranty.

Comment: @leinad13 the AC adapter is working because it has light and it's on(Green), So there is a possibility that the person who sold me gives me incorrect adapter, because i figured out that AC adapter compatible to my laptop version is Dell 65-Watt 3-Prong AC Adapter with 6 ft Power Cord from this lnik http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/category/ar/7683

Comment: Glad you may have found a fix - @DavidPostill, i considered saying that - but then remembered it could be second hand, and in some countries they may have no obligation to do anything once you have left the shop.

Comment: @leinad13  i'm sure that when i go back to the shop, there's no options, i must buy another adapter,  But first of all i want to ensure that the problem is from the adapter.